# What does the phrase “turnouts approved” mean?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, phraseology

What does the (apparently nonstandard judging by its absence in the [Pilot/Controller Glossary](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg.pdf)) phrase “turnouts approved” mean when given in the context of a takeoff clearance?

Comment: Do you think what you have heard could be something like: "Left turn out's approved"? (Meaning that the pilot is cleared to turn left after departure)

Comment: @J.Hougaard I don’t recall the turn direction being part of the call, which made me wonder whether it would really be at pilot’s discretion. Glad to see an ATC specialist participating in the community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When departing from a towered field pilots may request something other than a "standard" departure. As an example, consider the noise abatement procedures for my home field shown below:

[image: KFRG noise abatement - Arrivals/Departures]

When departing from Runway 14 the standard noise-abatement departure for light aircraft requires you to turn south (heading 190) when you pass the departure end of the runway.  This is obviously inconvenient if your destination is to the north, so you can request a northbound departure.
If the tower can accommodate your request they will clear you for the non-standard departure, usually with the phrase "left turn-out approved" or "northbound departure approved", and a heading if necessary.

Comment: I have gotten "turnout approved" on all sorts of departures, even charted noise abatement ones. Usually the tower (or ground in some airports) will ask  "say departure request" and that's when you can say "left crosswind" or "national cemetery", and get the approval.